# Print function is rendered before angular loads values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image: When i open view]

[image]

I need to get values like on first one image but when i call print function i get this like on second pictures.I tried

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function(){
$window.print
});
```

and i also tried to use `ng-binding` and `ng-cloak` but i always get results like on second image

I have page where i have this button:

i have **controller** where i have:

```
 $scope.printFunction = function ()
    {
        localStorage.setItem("payoutTime", $scope.testpayoutTime);
        localStorage.setItem("payoutAmount", $scope.testpayoutAmount);
        localStorage.setItem("pin", $scope.testticketPin);

        $window.open("/print");

    }
```

and when this **view** is open i have this controller on that view:

```
  $scope.ticketPin = localStorage.getItem("pin");
    $scope.payoutTime = localStorage.getItem("payoutTime");
    localStorage.payoutAmount = localStorage.getItem("payoutAmount");

        $window.print();
```

How can i render this variables before print function?

Comment: `$scope.$apply` i think you need

Comment: set ng-show to false first. and when u have all data from server set the ng-show to true.

Comment: @Grundy where i need $scope.$apply ?

Comment: @None before `$window.print();`

Comment: @Grundy its not working...do u have any other suggestion? :)

Comment: can you provide a sample plunker? :-)

Comment: @Grundy problem is that i dont know how to simulate that environment ... can i explain u what im trying to do? :)

Answer (score 0):

There in lies the problem. It’s a rat race: Whatever happens to get there first wins. Sometimes it’s the render, sometimes

we can use a slight hack with setTimeout().

```
 $scope.printFunction = {
afterRender: function () {
         localStorage.setItem("payoutTime", $scope.testpayoutTime);
         localStorage.setItem("payoutAmount", $scope.testpayoutAmount);
         localStorage.setItem("pin", $scope.testticketPin);

         $window.open("/print");
    },

    render: function () {
        //Render Your template
        setTimeout(this.afterRender.bind(this), 0);
    }
}
```

**Updated:**

There are a few solutions. The code needs to know when a value has changed.

Right now there is no way for our code to be directly notified of changes on an object.

Instead there are two main strategies.

1. One strategy is to use special objects, where data is set via
   methods, not property assignments. Then changes can then be noted,
   and the page can be updated. This has the downside in that we must
   extend some special object. Also, for assigning, we must use a more
   verbose form obj.set('key', 'value') instead of obj.key = 'value'.
2. AngularJS takes a different approach: allow any value to be used as
   a binding target. Then at the end of any JavaScript code turn, check
   to see if the value has changed. This may seem inneficient at first,
   but there are some clever strategies to reduce the performance hit.
   The big benefit is we can use normal objects and update our data
   however we want, and the changes will be noticed and reflected in
   our bindings.

[Demo JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m3tsA/1/light/)

For this strategy to work, we need to know when data has possibly changed, and this is where $scope.$apply comes into play.

i hope its help

Comment: is it possible to do it without hackish solution?

Comment: i want to avoid this setTimeout function...to call print function immediately

Comment: yes but that is hackish because user must wait some time to get values